# Minimum a-z flow and minimum capacity a-z cut

Tags: graph-theory

[image]

Hi! I am working on a Graph Theory problem. I was wondering when finding flow paths are you allowed to have a path that goes against the directed arrow of the graph? I was wondering if I could have the purple path in the previous graph because if I could it would affect how big |f| or the maximum capacity is! If anyone could explain, that would be great! Thanks so much!

Comment: The pink x's mean that the edge is saturated. L_1 (red), L_2 (blue), L_3 (green) are paths that I have found.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can go backwards along the edge $fc$ since its flow is at least $2$ (effectively diverting the flow along that edge to a different path). Alternatively, an unsaturated path that does not involve backward edges would be:
$$
a \to b \to f \to d \to g \to z
$$

Comment: Oh ok! Thank you so much! :) If you're interested, I actually found another one that is 14 if I'm correct! I can attach my picture if you would like to see it!

Comment: Ah yes, you're right, I missed it. Yes, it is possible to get a value of $14$.

Comment: Oh good! Then, I'm not just seeing things! haha Thanks again!

Comment: No problem! I'm actually studying for my graph theory final tomorrow, so this was good practice for me. =]

Comment: Oh good! Hope it goes well! :)